# same names matrix R

Tags: r, list, matrix

```
for usability
loopx<- list()
loopx[[1]] <- c(3,3)
loopx[[2]] <- c(2,4)
loopx[[3]] <- c(4,44)
loopx[[4]] <- c(8,5)
loopx[[5]] <- c(4,4)
```

It returns a 5 layer list
e.g.

loopx

[[1]]
[1] 3 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 4

[[3]]
[1] 4 44

[[4]]
[1] 8 5

[[5]]
[1] 4, 4

I then go

```
names(loopx) <- c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
unlist(loopx)
one1  one2 two1 two2 three1 thre2 four1 four2 five1 six2 
 3      3   2    4    4      44    8     5    4     4
```

How do I make the same names in the matrix without the 1 and 2 repeating it self

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub` to remove the digits and `setNames` to reassign the names.

```
unloopx <- unlist(loopx)
setNames(unloopx, sub("\\d+", "", names(unloopx)))

#  one   one   two   two three three  four  four  five  five 
#    3     3     2     4     4    44     8     5     4     4
```

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer, what if the column names are one1, one1, two2, two2. The code you said would remove the number. How would I over come this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `unlist`ing, we can `stack` it to two column data.frame and then convert to a named `vector` from the columns

```
with(stack(loopx)[2:1], setNames(values, ind))
# one   one   two   two three three  four  four  five  five 
#   3     3     2     4     4    44     8     5     4     4
```

---

Or we use `unlist` with `use.names = FALSE` and set the names by `rep`licating the `names`

```
setNames(unlist(loopx, use.names = FALSE), rep(names(loopx), lengths(loopx)))
#  one   one   two   two three three  four  four  five  five 
#   3     3     2     4     4    44     8     5     4     4
```

---

Or with `enframe/deframe` from `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
enframe(loopx) %>% 
       unnest(c(value)) %>%
       deframe
#  one   one   two   two three three  four  four  five  five 
#    3     3     2     4     4    44     8     5     4     4
```